# Implement tables for partial payments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm try to make a database for instalmentSales app but I feel like I'm carrying coals to Newcastle.

Every customer should have required payments every month and the due date and amount, so I'm creating table for the required payments to save every customer required payments. Which is usually 12 months or so.

Also what if customer paid a partial amount of the monthly payment, like if he paid 50% of the payment and is going to pay the rest after few days or even next month, so I'm creating another table to save paid payments and the date of it so I can check/access the partial amount and the date of it later.

I feel like I'm doing it totally wrong and I'm out of ideas

Comment: "carrying coals to Newcastle"???

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/carry--coals--to--newcastle ;)

Comment: Can you show us the model you have come up with so far (table definitions, ER-Diagram or anything like that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track; just call the "required payments" table Invoice and the "actual payments paid" table Payment. Since someone could in theory be paying multiple invoices with a single payment (e.g. they fell behind and are catching up), you probably couldn't use a foreign key here to make a one to many relationship between Invoice and Payment. You could do a many to many with a linking table if you want to track which payments are applied to which invoices.

Comment: can u explain why i can't go one to many relationship between invoice and payments, like invoice could be paid with 2 payment or 2 invoice can be paid with 1 payment

Comment: @DaleK i know what meaning of many to many relationship lol
i wanted to create new payment records even if customer paid 2 invoices or so 
new record for every invoice, or even partial payment
so if i'm stick with a payment to pay a partial due money for past month and the current month due money, if done with a single payment record how could i check how much paid from the past month in this payment? couldn't find a way to handle it, it's gonna point to the payment with the full value, i know its paid from those 2 payments but no details

Comment: @Felixanius if you use a many-to-many linking record, then you add a column for the amount to the linking record. There is a reason accounting software is expensive - its because its complicated :)